# Left Join Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

We have two table where where table A and table B need to be join. Relationship between table A and B is one to many. We can join now using this LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.aID=tableB.aID. We would like to ensure only one record is join on table B and that is the latest record only. We now get more then one record.

```
SELECT student.*

FROM   student
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT B1.*
                  FROM medicalRecord AS B1
                         LEFT JOIN medicalRecord AS B2
                                ON B1.studentID = B2.studentID
                                   AND B1.checkUpDate< B2.checkUpDate
                  WHERE  B2.studentID IS NULL) AS b
              ON ( student.studentID = medicalRecord.studentID)

Where student.studentID=45
```

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: "Last" when sorted by what column? Please post some schema.

Comment: not question , no code , no try no ..., just help me

Comment: I think you are asking for a distinct question than left join, please change the title

Comment: @alberto yes is for distinct and only the latest value of table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume you want to get only the record from the child table with the highest value in the `val` column. You could use:

```
SELECT a.*,
       b.*
FROM   a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT B1.*
                  FROM   b AS B1
                         LEFT JOIN b AS B2
                                ON B1.aID = B2.aID
                                   AND B1.val < B2.val
                  WHERE  B2.aID IS NULL) AS b
              ON ( a.aID = b.aID )
```

The idea is to use a subquery to filter the table for the records with the greatest values in the `val` column, then to join on *that*.

Comment: is it possible to avoid the subquery will it work if I use grouping mechanism?

Comment: I have updated my question based on your suggestion but it gives me error as medicalRecord.studentID as unknown column and I have double check the column do exist.